# C# Code for Sending email from Office365 with modern authentication

Tags: c#, email, smtp, office365

Need steps to send the email using office365 account with modern authentication.
Created the application and client on Azure AD directory.
In my code, always getting error:
Message=535: 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [DX1P273CA0007.AREP273.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

Can anyone advise.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What have you tried already? What options have you researched and considered? We are not a code writing service. Please edit your post with more details about what you've researched and what you've tried, and any specific issues you've run into.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get your answers here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#smtp-protocol-exchange
Cheers,
Gonkas